# Best practice to post data with web-services

Tags: android, web-services, cakephp

I created an android app where I tap on the screen to put some waypoints , get their position and some extra data, then post the data using cakephp. I want to know what are the best practice to send data for my case ?

Example, should I post every point once I tap on the screen or store all the data and post it once for all or post every point into a temporary table then when I click submit I post the data to the real table ?

I really want to know if there are other solution to optimize my application and the loading time ! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If the positions are not used by other users until the user completes their interaction I'd save all the positions and send them as a http POST in JSON format as an array [[0,100],[100,331]] or [{"x":0,"y":100},{"x":100,"y":331}] depending on if you're really wanting to optimize it or not use one or the other.

If the positions are used by other users on the site in real time, send every position as they are selected.

Comment: but what if I add for example 10 points with a lot of attributes ? it will not be a problem to save it all and then post it ?